# Simple Ajax call to Django server results with slow response time - slow TTFB

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

First of all, I do not have lots of experience with django, js and ajax, but this is quite a simple example and I cannot find the reason why my ajax calls take a lot of time.
My current dev configuration is: windows 7, python 3.6, django 1.10.5, server running on localhost - 127.0.0.1:8000

Basically, I click on a button (in specific buttons group), this activates ajax and depending on the reply, color of the button is updated.

Info: In reality, I use something a bit more complex, but since it was also slow I tried to simplify it, to see where it goes wrong, but I still cannot find the reason.

Code ajax:

```
$('body').on('click', '.some_module', function(){
        var $something= $(this);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'some_function/',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {'some_name' : "just_example"},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                ...some_action_where_i_change_color_of_button...
                ...not important because even if it's empty, it's slow...
            }
        });
    });
```

Code django, views.py:

```
def change_module(request):
    # ...for example using hardcoded return...
    data = {
        'success': True,
        'curr': 'something',
        'selected': [],
        'previous': []
    }
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
    # tried also JSONResponse, the same feedback
```

So by using this example, I wait for an update for more than 1s and **TTFB is always around 1s**. TTFB is related to server side, but I really do not see how it could be so slow since I am sending hardcoded json with barely few string elements inside.

[Chrome developer tools TTFB image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYMxM.png)

I would appreciate if someone who had a similar problem would share his solution with me.

Comment: so when you used JSONResponse(data), same 1s TTFB?

Comment: yes, same. Maybe forgot to mention that server is running on localhost (127.0.0.1:8000)

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would like to use Django Generic View class.
Look at the current documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/

Look at this example:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views.generic import View
class MyViewClass(View):
   def get(self, request):
      data = {
          'success': True,
          'curr': 'something',
          'selected': [],
          'previous': []
      }
      return JSONResponse(data)
```

And in your js:
        Something about type:

> "You should use type if you're using versions of jQuery prior to
>   1.9.0"

```
           $.ajax({
                method: "GET", #HERE TRY TO USE METHOD INSTEAD OF TYPE
                url: "/some_function",
                data: {'some_name' : "just_example"},
                datatype: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    ... Do Something here...
                }
            }),
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will try to learn more about Django Generic View class. However, I've implemented this and I still have the same problem. There is the same delay of approx 1s. Replacing _post_ by _method_ also did not help me.